# Use regex to capture characters between colon and comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, eslint

EsLint is outputting errors when capturing a string that has already output a string stating the weather.

The string example:

```
let example = 'Current Conditions: Mostly Cloudy, 16.5°C';
```

The goal is to capture the string to describe the weather condition, 'Mostly cloudy'.

The regex outputting an error:

```
let wecur_tcond = $(example).text(/\:(.*?)\,/g,"");
console.log(wecur_tcond);
```

And the error output:

```
Unnecessary escape character: \:  no-useless-escape
Unnecessary escape character: \,  no-useless-escape
```

Edit: Without the backslashes to escape the characters, console outputs:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:Current Conditions: Mostly Cloudy, 16.5°C
```

Comment: Are you confused about the error message? It says that you don't need the backslash before the colon and comma. Just do as you are told.

Comment: Updated with further error code after following obvious instruction

Comment: Actually, why are you using jQuery syntax on a string? You should just do: `example.replace(/:(.*?),/g,"")`

Comment: @canacast `The goal is to capture the string to describe the weather condition, 'Mostly cloudy'.` but in your code you're replacing `Mostly cloudy` instead of capturing it

Comment: @canacast you want to get `Mostly cloudy` as output or everything else except `Mostly cloudy` ?

Comment: @CodeManiac yes! Definitely have this expression backwards I think...

Comment: @canacast can you please update post with the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:` and `,` is not a special characters so you do not need to escape, ( `:` is special character when used inside capture group just after the `?`i.e `(?:)` )

Also you don't need `()` here as you're not using reference of captured group anywhere,

Also regex can be improved to `[^,]+` instead of `.*?`

```js
let example = 'Current Conditions: Mostly Cloudy, 16.5°C';
let wecur_tcond = example.replace(/:[^,]+,/g,"");
console.log(wecur_tcond);
```

> The goal is to capture the string to describe the weather condition,
>   'Mostly cloudy'

```js
let example = 'Current Conditions: Mostly Cloudy, 16.5°C';
let wecur_tcond = example.match(/:[^,]+/)[0].replace(/^:\s*/,'')
console.log(wecur_tcond);
```